# How to use std::auto_ptr to achieve covariance assignment?

Tags: c++, templates, auto-ptr

I have the following use case but I can't figure out how to make it work:

```
enum MyTemplateEnum { A, B };
template<MyTemplateEnum T = A>
class MyTemplateClass<T> {
   // ...
};

std::string argument = ...;
std::auto_ptr<MyTemplateClass<> > instance;
if (argument == "a") {
  std::auto_ptr<MyTemplateClass<A> > temp(new MyTemplateClass<A>(...));
  instance = temp;
} else
if (argument == "b") {
  std::auto_ptr<MyTemplateClass<B> > temp(new MyTemplateClass<B>(...));
  instance = temp;
}
```

this results in compilation error because I basically can't assign a concrete realization `std::auto_ptr<MyTemplateClass<A> >` to a generic version `std::auto_ptr<MyTemplateClass<> >`.

Comment: What does `MyTemplateClass` look like? Are you trying to assign a pointer to `MyTemplateClass<B>` to a pointer to `MyTemplateClass<A>`?

Comment: I would like the covariance assignment to work i.e. assign the specialized pointer to a generic reference disregard what the template realization is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a common base class for all instantiations of the `MyTemplateClass<T>` template. Otherwise all the instatiations are unrelated classes.

```
class MyTemplateBase {
public:
    // Don't forget virtual destructor.
    virtual ~MyTemplateBase() {}
};

template<typename T = A>
class MyTemplateClass : public MyTemplateBase {
};

std::auto_ptr<MyTemplateBase> instance;
if (argument == "a") {
  instance.reset(new MyTemplateClass<A>(...));
} else if (argument == "b") {
  instance.reset(new MyTemplateClass<B>(...));
}
```

Note that `std::auto_ptr` is obsolete. If possible use `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr` instead.